# Subrion CMS Nginx Installation Issue

Tags: php, apache, nginx, server, content-management-system

I would like to try out Subrion CMS however, I've had issues getting this to work.

Is Apache mod-rewrite required? Will this require the use of Apache? Can Nginx only be used as a reverse proxy with Subrion?

Debian 8 - Nginx - MariaDB - PHP5-FPM - Subrion CMS

Installation screen says everything looks good. Permissions and ownership and non-issue. I think this is a Nginx rewrite issue as I notice the url will become "/install/install/" upon submission however, the page remains the same as if you were to scroll to top. In the meantime I am going without a CMS so there is no pressing rush on this.

If you are running Subrion CMS with Nginx I would appreciate your take on this situation. Thanks for reading.

Comment: I don't think you would be too massively downvoted, I think the problem with your question that it is not about programming. It more like a sysadm question. If the serverfault would be a friendly place, I would suggest to visit them, but so my current best idea to re-ask this on http://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Subrion CMS can be run on Nginx server. Here is the configuration that will work for nginx:

```
server {
    listen      80; # make sure there is no conflict with apache server listening on port 80
    server_name subrion_domain.com; # your website domain name

    root        /var/www/subrion; # absolute path to your subrion core files
    index       index.php;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page  404  /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /install/ {
        rewrite ^/install/(.*)$ /install/index.php?_p=$1;
    }

    # deny access to apache .htaccess files
    location ~ /\.ht
    {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

Anyhow, please note you might have issue with admin dashboard. You will need to update admin URL, change the default "admin" dashboard URL to any value, and clear tmp/ folder. This will work fine.

Let me know if you need any assistance. I will be happy to help.

Comment: Thank you so much! I posted a comment as an answer below, if you have time maybe read it over and let me know your thoughts. Truly, truly appreciate your time and work!